# jQuery : how to indent a infinite loop?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, infinite-loop

Here what's happening. I wish to store some data from multiple lists on Twitter. Each request return 20 array max, so if the list have more than 20 members you have to do multiple requests (using the cursor attribute to get the next one). So i thought : infinite loop to call and parse the `json`.

Basically what i want to do : call the first json(with cursor value set to -1) and stock the data. Then call the second `json` (with cursor value = to next_cursor_str value of the previous `json`). Then call the third one... etc and stop if the loop if the next_cursor_str value = 0 (that mean it's the last `json`). That was my first draft :

```
var interval = setInterval(function(i){ /*start the loop*/
    if (i==1) {var cursor = '&cursor=-1'} else {var cursor = '&cursor='+json.next_cursor_str+''} /* set the value of cursor ine the request. The first request have to be cursor=-1*/
        var url='twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent('lists/members.json?owner_screen_name=flavienhamon&slug=lexpress&skip_status=true'+cursor+''); /*Make the request*/
            $.getJSON(url, function(json) { processData(json); /*store data for processing*/ console.log(json); 



    if (json.next_cursor_str == 0) {window.clearInterval(interval);}; /*stop the loop if*/
            });   
},5000); /*end of loop fonction*/
```

The infinite loop work, has the stop event. But i can't set the first json being call to be the "cursor=-1" and `'&cursor='+json.next_cursor_str+''` doesn't work since json as not being define yet.

So i make a few change :

```
var url='twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent('lists/members.json?owner_screen_name=flavienhamon&slug=lexpress&skip_status=true&cursor=-1'); /*call manually the first json*/
  $.getJSON(url, function(json) { processData(json); console.log(json); NombreCompteJ1 = json.users.length;
    var interval = setInterval(function(i){ /*start the loop*/
            var url='twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent('lists/members.json?owner_screen_name=flavienhamon&slug=lexpress&skip_status=true&cursor='+json.next_cursor_str+''); /*Make the request*/
                $.getJSON(url, function(json) { processData(json); /*store data for processing*/ console.log(json); 



        if (json.next_cursor_str == 0) {window.clearInterval(interval);}; /*stop the loop if*/
                });   
    },5000); /*end of loop fonction*/       

});
```

This time, the first json is call and proccess without a problem. Then the loop start to call the second json, process it, and... call the second one again.

console capture : http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/223/infiniteloop.png

`&cursor='+json.next_cursor_str+'` call the next_cursor_str value of the first json, again, and again, instead of calling the value of the previous element of the loop.

Someone can explain how to fix this ? I'm learning jQuery and JS since two days, i'm reading a lot, but i can't find anything on this. I could use a hand to learn !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`, so you can pass a closure with the updated cursor each time. And define your code as a named function so you can call it in the `setTimeout()`.

```
function getData(cursor) {
    var url='twitter-proxy.php?url='+encodeURIComponent('lists/members.json?owner_screen_name=flavienhamon&slug=lexpress&skip_status=true&cursor='+cursor);
    $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
        processData(json);
        console.log(json);
        var next_cursor = json.next_cursor_str;
        if (next_cursor != 0) {
            setTimeout(function() { getData(next_cursor); }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Start the loop with:

```
getData(-1);
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar , thx for your time. I don't undestand a few thing in the code you just post : how do you set the first cursor value to -1 (hence start the loop) and how `if (var next_cursor = json.next_cursor_str) {...}` can work ? `next_cursor` can't be equal to `json.next_cursor_str`. (the `=` is "Unexpected token ="). Now your code made think of sometting, can we start a loop IF `json.next_cursor_str`> 0 ? (im trying to do so has we speak)

Comment: I updated the answer with the starting call. The `if` statement isn't comparing `next_cursor` to `json.next_cursor_str`, it's assigning `json.next_cursor_str` to `next_cursor` (`=` is assignment, `==` would be comparison). So it assigns the variable and tests if it's not zero.

Comment: Thx a lot ! It work ! And with your explanations and your second code, i've understood how (that what i was looking for). I added some stuff to stop the loop. Thx @Barman ! (i updated my first post with the final code)

Comment: You don't need to do `clearTimeout(timeout)`, since we don't start the timeout when `next_cursor` is 0.

Comment: Arf, i'm still missing something to min the code so. When i loaded your code, the loop work, but it doesn't stop, that's why i added the `clearTimeout(timeout)`.

Comment: Changed the test condition, try now. The original test didn't work as expected because `next_cursor` is a string.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. 75% of programming languages use that syntax.